# Comparing dates in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

Being experienced in PHP, I lack in the area of comparing two dates in database.

I have two values stored in my database. Which are simply just unix time stamps.

Value 1: `post_time`

Value 2: `expire_time`

The expire time is just 7 days after the posted time. I simply need to get all posts that haven't "expired".

For the time being I've been using: `if(($post['post_time']) >= time() - (60*60*24*7))`, which works fine. But I'd much rather find a solution right in the query to get the results. Rather than pull all results and then filter them later.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT id, uid, title, description, 
       price, image, tags, post_type, 
       category, post_time, expire_time 
  FROM posts 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: convert to mysql syntax: .. `WHERE post_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())  - (60*60*24*7)`

Comment: Hmm let me try that @Dagon

Comment: @kingkero, it is, i just thought it was clearer

Comment: if leap seconds\hours\days\years matter to you, this is not the correct approach

Comment: Well your solution does work. But for things such as leap seconds\hours\days\years, what would be a better approach? @Dagon

Comment: the real date functions instead of basic arithmetic: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: where post_time >= TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,7,post_time)

Comment: That solution doesn't work @JorgeCampos

Comment: Reading your question and the code you did, there is nothing to do with the expire_time colum you are just calculating the post_time with the actual time plus 7 day therefore my code wouldn't work as you expect of course. Try this: `where post_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` If this is the right approach, please fix your question.

Comment: My question was very clear about the functionality of which I am looking for. I want to get posts that haven't expired evaluating two time stamps. A post time, and an expire time. @JorgeCampos

Comment: why is your code testing for the actual time then? `if(($post['post_time']) >= time() - (60*60*24*7))`

Comment: That was a work around solution as I didn't know of a solution right in the query... That is checked AFTER getting the results from that query. @JorgeCampos

Comment: But I will say however, your second solution has also failed. @JorgeCampos

Comment: I do appreciate the help though. @JorgeCampos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69360/discussion-between-jason-bassett-and-jorge-campos).

Comment: As for your statement `The expire time is just 7 days after the posted time. I simply need to get all posts that haven't "expired"` it should do the trick the `where post_time < expired_time` I'm considering with this that the expire_time is already filled.

Comment: Yes, `expire_time` is already filled. But again, that solution doesn't work either. @JorgeCampos

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question and what would be the desired result from that sample? I really am curious about why it is not working.

Comment: This query literally just gets all posts in my database and orders by random and limits the results to 8 at a time. I just need the results to be within 7 days of `post_time`. Anything greater than 7 days after `post_time` counts as an expired post. @JorgeCampos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it the way @Dagon did it:

```
SELECT id, uid, title, description, 
       price, image, tags, post_type, 
       category, post_time, expire_time 
  FROM posts WHERE post_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (60*60*24*7) 
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8
```